# Twilio Call Forwarding Custom Number?

Tags: twilio

Theres a way to forward calls on Twilio. So the idea is you would call your twilio number, and it will forward your call to another number. See below:

```
<Response> <Dial> +13105555555 </Dial> </Response>
```

However, is it possible to change the +13105555555 number to your keypad inputs? So you can easily change who you want to forward the call to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio basic and call forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500015/twilio-basic-and-call-forwarding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Twilio Studio. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide)

Log into your Twilio account and navigate to the Studio Dashboard (https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard), then tap the + icon to create a new flow. Name your flow for example **"Forward Call"**, then continue to the Studio's canvas.

---

First, add a **"Gather Input On Call"** widget and connect it to the **"Incoming Call"** trigger. For the **"TEXT TO SAY"** field you can input something like **"Hello... please enter the number you'd like to call..."**. Click on the red "Save" button at the bottom.

Next, add a **"Connect Call To"** widget and connect it to the dangling **"User Pressed Keys"** dot from the **"Gather Input On Call"** widget. There is a field under **"Single Number"** select box, type `{{widgets.gather_1.Digits}}` if your **"Gather Input On Call"** widget is named `gather_1`. Click on the red "Save" button at the bottom.

Click on the **"Publish"** button at the top to save the flow.

---

Once the flow is published, the last thing to do is to hook it up to your Twilio phone number. In the Twilio console, select **"Manage Numbers"** and choose the phone number that you would like to connect.

Scroll down to the section for Voice and Fax, then select **"Studio Flow"** from the first drop-down and your flow name (**"Forward Call"**) from the second drop-down. Click save.

---

Here is a picture that might help:

[image]

---

Also this tutorial can help to understand the steps: (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-an-ivr).

Comment: Thanks! super helpful. So if I follow the procedure, does that mean my Twilio number will be calling the number being forwarded to? in the picture, I see a caller ID field. Can you set the field as your original phone number to hide the fact you're using a Twilio number?

Comment: As is it will be you Twilio number. About setting another caller id, it has to be a verified number, more info. here: (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180148-Unable-to-Display-a-Business-Name-or-Custom-Text-as-Caller-ID), and this (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-verified-outbound-caller-ID-with-Twilio)

Comment: Once you verify your number with Twilio, you can set the caller id to something like this `{{+15557779999}}`, where `15557779999` is your number, not a Twilio number.